# Some Deprecated UI Objects Causes Memory Leak On iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, uialertview, ios8.4

I tried UIAlertView and UIActionSheet objects that causes memory leak in iOS8.4 SDK. New objects that coming from iOS8 (such as UIAlertController) that supports minimum iOS8 OS. How can handle this leak with iOS8 and before releases?

Example code piece that causes leak;

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" 
                                                message:@"" 
                                                delegate:self 
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check the class availability. For example, if you want to check whether to use `UIAlertController` or `UIAlertView` then:

```
if ([UIAlertController class]) {
   // use UIAlertController

} else {
  // use UIAlertView

}
```